# Powershell Where command not working

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains elements separated by an '=' sign (i.e. color1=red, color2=blue, etc.

I used the import-csv command and provide headers (i.e.

```
$Import_Cfg = Import-Csv .\Env.cfg -Header Title,Setting -Delimiter =
```

)

Now this works fine if I want to assign a particular item to another variable if I know the index number and I have used that approach but it won't always work for me because I don't always know what other data will be there.

I thought that by using something like:

```
$MyColor1 = $Import_Cfg.Setting |where {$_.Title -match "Blue"}

$MyColor2 = $Import_Cfg.Setting |where {$_.Title -match "Red"}
```

it should work, but I get no returns for either item.  When I type in $Import_cfg I can see the entire array (without the "=" signs).  If I tell use the command

```
$MyColor1 = $import_cfg[0].setting
```

I get the right answer.

Obviously I'm not using colors but a bunch of different items that I need to assign to variables for use elsewhere.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Everything I've read says that what I have above should work.

Please no flames on why I'm using import-csv vs get-content.  I'm sure either will work.  This is an approach that I've used and computationally it doesn't matter.  If programatically it makes a difference I'm all ears!!!

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Remove `.Setting` from your commands and try it again.

Comment: When i do that I end up with both elements.  I just need the one on the right.

Comment: Ah... but if I then do $Mycolor.Setting I do get just the element.  That sort of works.  I'd rather not have to add '.setting' to the variable when I want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `Setting` property itself has no `Title` property.

You need to apply `Where` *before* you extract the property value you need (as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344798/powershell-where-command-not-working#comment56431300_34344798)):

```
$BlueSettings = $Import_Cfg |where {$_.Title -match "Blue"} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Setting
```

or, using property enumeration:

```
$BlueSettings = ($Import_Cfg |where {$_.Title -match "Blue"}).Setting
```